# Convert Array To Nested JSON in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, logic

Basically i want to create a tree structure. For example if you have an array of four items ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] then i need a JSON from this which should be

```
{a: {b: {c: {d: 0} } } }
```

last item of JSON have value of 0 or it can be anything except object.

Comment: What did your try already?

Comment: _"Recursion"_ comes to mind...

Comment: Do you want a JSON string or a Javascript Object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The conversion steps are straightforward with simple loop:

- Reverse the array, so the last becomes the first to convert (and it becomes the inner-most element of JSON).
- Iterate through each element, make key-value pair of the object, wrap it repeatedly.
- Done

**Sample code:**

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']; // input array
var json = {}; // output object
array.reverse().forEach(function(el){
    if (Object.keys(json).length==0){
        json[el] = 0;
    }
    else{
        var outer = {};
        outer[el] = json;
        json = outer;
    }
});
```

**Output**

> {"a": {"b": {"c": {"d": 0} } } }

Comment: Using `reduceRight` would have been a much simpler solution, if you are going to use ES5 methods.

Answer (score 2):

In an ES5 environment.

```js
var data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    jsObject = data.reduceRight(function (acc, datum) {
        var val = {};
            
        val[datum] = acc;
        
        return val;
    }, 0),
    jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsObject);

document.getElementById('out').textContent = jsonString;
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```